# How to make peeling edges of a paper

Tags: modeling, edges

I want to model a piece of paper that has curled edges, similar to those created when one keeps a sheet of paper unprotected for a long time, the edges will somewhat shrink. I tried creating a thinned cube and beveling it, but it only gives me rounded corners.

Any thoughts? I am trying to create this effect:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to give a look at the [Page Curl Tool](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/82972) @ blendswap.com

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/editing/deform.html

Answer (score 12):

There are 2 main ways to curl a plane, using the SimpleDeform>Bend modifier, or using the Curve modifier with a curled curve object. I personally think the Curve solution is more accurate and controllable.

1. Create a curve with a long flat portion and curled portion at the end.
2. Line the curve up diagonally with the plane so that the curl part of the curve is beyond the corner of the page
3. Add the Curve modifier to the page and select the curly curve object
4. You may need to reposition the page or the curl object to get them to line up properly.
5. Keyframe the position of the curve so that it moved diagonally across the corner of the page. As it does so the corner will curl up.
6. You will need the page mesh to be fairly subdivied, and may also need to add a subsurf modifier to smooth it out even more.

[image]