# How to model a folded magazine?

Tags: modeling

The primary part I'm confused about:

The thickness of the magazine with slightly bent pages underneath other pages?

Do I model each page individually?

I would like the edges of the underlying pages to show also.

What is best practice? (going for photo realism, its ok if its high poly)

[image]

Comment: For simple page deform check this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54114/how-to-make-peeling-edges-of-a-paper for the whole magazine, well... I'm struggling with this too. Check also this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBIxcm-T3Oo&t=40s

Answer (score 3):

I would model the profile of the open magazine -

[image: magazine profile]

then extrude it to the height of the magazine and add a solidify modifier.
[image: extruded and thickness]

One end can be scaled out to get the variation at the top. Apply the solidify and add a crease to the outer edges, then use an edge split and subsurf modifier to finish it off. Some parts can then be expanded where the pages are separated.

[image: finished magazine]

I would then add the "space" between the pages and the page variations to the texture.