# How to animate a peeling orange

Tags: animation

I am trying to make an animation of an orange where the skin peels off but do not know how to go about it. Could someone explain how to get this effect?? Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54114/how-to-make-peeling-edges-of-a-paper

Comment: Here you can get a very easy way of making the orange skin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0uS7T0AMVw